# Convert name ordered list to grade ordered list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, asymptotic-complexity

This is an interview question.

Provide an optimal solution to achieve this:
**Input**: List of student records, sorted by name.
**Output**: List of student records, sorted by grade, then by name
Grade can be 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'

**Sample Input**

```
Name | Grade  
Adam | B  
Ashley | C  
Boxer | A  
Britney | A
Caroline | E  
David | B
```

**Sample Output**

```
Name | Grade  
Boxer | A  
Britney | A
Adam | B  
David | B  
Ashley | C  
Caroline | E
```

I proposed this solution:

1. Insert the list into a has map
2. Hash-map has 5 buckets, one per grade
3. Insert the students sharing the same grade into one bucket.
4. Chaining is used to manage collision
5. To avoid `O(n2)` complexity for insertion, I stored the last node pointer in the bucket, which achieves `O(1)` random insertion complexity.

My question is whether my solution is correct?
If yes, what can be improved?
If no, what other data structure could be used to achieve this?

Comment: Your approach is fine and efficient here.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is`O(n)` time, with `O(n)` extra space, and is basically a variation of [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) (and is probably what the interviewer wanted to hear).

In terms of time complexity - this is the best asymptotic complexity you can achieve, since the output size itself is `O(n)`.

Note that you don't actually need a hash map, you can just have an array of linked-lists, where grade A maps to first entry of the array, grade B maps to second entry, and so on...

---

However, one small optimization is actually a trade-off:

You can have `O(n)` time with `O(1)` space - by having worse constants for your time by iterating once per possible grade:

```
for each grade (descending order):
   for each student in list:
       if student.grade == grade: 
           print student
```

This will be `O(G*n)` time, where G is the number of possible grades, but since it is a constant here - it decays into `O(n)` time, with `O(1)` space, but as said - it is not a free lunch - constants are much worse here.

Comment: I did not understand your optimization. I iterate the list per grade only once to print the result in my solution.

Comment: @cppcoder This "optimization" is a trade-off. It costs more time, but saves you space. Since it's an interview question, I would have given both options and pointing out the advantage and disadvantage of each approach.